# Store byte value in char*

Tags: c, pointers, casting, hex, byte

I've got byte value like 0x1F and i would like to store this hexa value in a char* like char*="1F"
this is my code:

```
uint8_t *pBlockAddr=0x1F;
printf("%02X", pBlockAddr); //Print 1F
```

Comment: `sprintf`?.....

Comment: Undefined behaviour. What is it that you're really trying to achieve here.

Comment: `uint8_t pBlockAddr=0x1F; char mys_string[3] = {0}; sprintf(mys_string, "%02X", pBlockAddr);`

Answer (score 3):

You probably want this:

```
char mystring[3];
snprintf(mystring, sizeof(mystring), "%02X", 0x1f);

printf("%s\n", mystring);
```

Comment: Please use `snprintf` over `sprintf` whenever possible.

Comment: Thanks, i would like append the value in my char[] in a loop so how adapt snprintf for the loop ?

Comment: @joflll that's another question. I'd suggest to ask another question.